# Semi transparent objects show fuzzy halos when in shadow

Tags: glsl, html5, webgl, alpha-blending

I'm having some issues when drawing a semi transparent object after an opaque object, and the object is in the shadows.

[image]

On the left, the torch is rendered just fine, I can see a nice blend of the border pixels with the wall behind it. On the right, I'm far away that the wall and torch are in shadows (I don't have ambient light) and as you can see, the border of the flame is rendered in the dark.

I guess I should specify that I'm writing my own engine.

Here is my WebGL enabled attributes and blend function:

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

I tried with different blendFunc parameters, but I always have one issue or another.

Here is my vertex shader

```
    attribute vec3 aPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTexcoord;
    attribute vec3 aNormal;

    uniform mat4 uTransform;
    uniform mat4 uProjection;
    uniform mat4 uWorldTransform;

    varying vec2 vTexcoord;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = uProjection * uTransform * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

      vTexcoord = aTexcoord;
      vNormal = (uWorldTransform * vec4(aNormal, 0.0)).xyz;
      vWorldPosition = (uWorldTransform * vec4(aPosition, 1.0)).xyz;
    }
```

And my fragment Shader

```
#define MAX_LIGHTS 8

    precision mediump float;

    struct Light {
      vec4 color;
      vec3 position;
      float radius;
    };

    uniform sampler2D uTexture;
    uniform vec4 uColor;
    uniform Light uLights[MAX_LIGHTS];

    varying vec2 vTexcoord;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

    void main(void) {
      vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, vTexcoord) * uColor;
      if (color.a == 0.0) {
        discard;
      }

      vec4 reflectedLight = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
      for (int i=0;i<MAX_LIGHTS;i++) {
        vec3 distanceVector = uLights[i].position - vWorldPosition;
        vec3 lightDirection = normalize(distanceVector);
        float distance = distanceVector.x * distanceVector.x + distanceVector.y * distanceVector.y + distanceVector.z * distanceVector.z;

        float attenuation = clamp(1.0 - distance / (uLights[i].radius * uLights[i].radius), 0.0, 1.0);
        attenuation *= attenuation;

        reflectedLight += (max(dot(vNormal, lightDirection), 0.0) * uLights[i].color) * attenuation;
      }

      gl_FragColor = color * reflectedLight;
    }
```

I'm using only one light, the one from the player, with these parameters:

```
color: vec4(1, 1, 1, 1)
radius: 6
position: player.position
```

And finally, I'm uniforming the lights like:

```
scene.lights.forEach((light: LightPoint, index: number) => {
      this._gl.uniform3f(this._shader.uniforms[`uLights[${index}].position`], light.position.x, light.position.y, light.position.z);
      this._gl.uniform4f(this._shader.uniforms[`uLights[${index}].color`], light.color.r, light.color.g, light.color.b, light.color.a);
      this._gl.uniform1f(this._shader.uniforms[`uLights[${index}].radius`], light.radius);
    });
```

The light color, position, and radius work just fine. I think is an issue with the blending, but I'm not sure, I've been toying with the blendFunc and the shader but I haven't been able to fix this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. Apparently the alpha was being mixed with the background color of the html body (white in my case but I did try it with other colors as well). So the fix is to add this when getting the context:

`const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', { alpha: false });`